# Non NULL datetime values from a SELECT statement without table

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a small bash function **that works perfectly well** designed to check a date's validity abusing MySQL because it is way faster than using GNU date. The aim is to return a validated date in the format YYYYmmdd to be used as input to other commands. Here:

```
function checkdate { for dd in $(seq $1 $2) ; do mysql -BNe "SELECT DATE_FORMAT($dd,'%Y%m%d')" | grep -v NULL ; done ; }
```

As I already commented it works quite nicely, but I find it sort of ugly to have to filter out the NULL values with a `grep -v`.

As somebody requested MCVE here they are, brace yourself for extremely complex output!

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('20160228','%Y%m%d') ;
20160228
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('20160229','%Y%m%d') ;
NULL
```

Who would have guessed that? But wait, there is more! What does this evil looking `grep -v` do there? OMG! we need definitely an MCMVE for that right now to protect the galaxy from being absorbed by the Sagitarius black hole:

```
echo NULL | grep NULL
NULL
echo NULL | grep -v 'NULL'
:tumbleweed:
```

Note the artistically placed `-v`after this weird word `grep`, neat, huh?
So, basically what the function does is that:

```
checkdate 20160227 20160231
20160227
20160228
20160229
```

That's it. It returns a list of valid dates conveniently (for me) formatted as YYYYmmdd, MySQL's datetime functions are perfectly happy with this format.

And my question is:

*Is there a more elegant way to do that in pure SQL without having to recur to grep -v ?*

Comment: In so far as this question relates to SQL, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In what way do you consider a single integer a valid or invalid date?

Comment: In what way do you consider a string with  random characters composed off ciphers, dashes, slashes, dots, colons and eventually some letters a valid date? 
Well, that was the question the guys after SQL asked themselves too and this is why they invented the nifty datetime functions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to believe this is faster.  But if you do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DATE_FORMAT($dd, '%Y%m%d'))
```

Then you will get 0 when it is not valid and 1 when it is valid.

Comment: I forgot to say that I want to get rid of the NULLs but get the validate dates as output, I used to do this with date -d $dd +'%Y%m%d' it does the same skipping the invalid dates but is very slow. Editing the question, thanks, may be useful for some other stuff ;)